# How to compile only graphics without text in LaTeX?

Tags: compiling

I have a large TeX document, containing over 800 figures and graphics as well as a lot of text (around 600 pages). We have to sort the figures and might even give them a little rework, thus I would like to produce a document only containing the figures and no text. As the numbering of the figures includes the chapters' numbers, we might leave all chapters.
Ideas such as inserting % or working with \begin{comment} \end{comment} seems not very suitable. I am certain such a document should not have been created in the first place but this discussion is already too late. I thought of setting font size as veeeeery small, so it seems like no text but I don't know if this is a reasonable idea.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You could use [package `endfloat`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) and then cut the figure pages from the end of the generated PDF.